How to convert HSV Values to Hexcode Format
Is it possible to convert directly HSV values to Hexcode format?
Dataframe of HSV Values:
My code:
import colorsys

def hsv_to_hex(h,s,v):
return '#' + ('{:x}{:x}{:x}').format(h,s,v)

st.write(hsv_to_hex(66,172,17))

and the result returns the following hexcode:
#42ac11 (Hexcode)

But my problem is that when I check #42ac11 it is the rgb color converted to hexacode  instead of hsv value.
I want to convert my HSV Values to Hexacode to change the color of the markers and show legend hexacode for me able to plot it like in the image below.
Example Chart I want to achieve:
Is there a way to make it directly converted without modification in the dataframe?

HSV values do not map directly to RGB, they need to be converted first. And colorsys has a hsv_to_rgb function to do the work for you.

Converting HSV to RGB requires a formula  -
Python, actually has had it in its standard library since the dawn of time - there is the colorsys module in the stdlib.
However, it works with floating point values in the 0.0-1.0 range - so, some code is needed if you want to convert your component values as integers.
Of course, just import colorsys does nothing - although possible, almost no package will have a global side-effect just by being imported (except from __future__ import .... statements which affect the way the Python code itself is compiled). You have to call the functions inside it.
That said, I think this could be your function (give or take "1" at the extreme boundaries:
import colorsys

def hsv_to_hex(h,s,v):
    r, g, b = (int(255 * component) for component in colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(h / 255, s / 255, v / 255))
    return f"#{r:02x}{g:02x}{b:02x}"

I am assuming the values you have for the HSV components are normalized in the 0-255 range.  There is another, more usual convention, where they are 0-360 for H and 0-100 for S and V  - change the divisors accordingly in the function above. (You have 172 for S, so it can´t be in the 0-100 range)

No, the hexcode is a representation of RGB, not HSV. You'll need to convert HSV to RGB with a formula like this first (or use a library).
Also your data does not look like typical HSV numbers, especially with saturations of "172". If they do actually represent HSV you would need to normalise to a 0 - 1 range before conversion.

Python has a builtin library for the conversion - the colorsys module the O.P. mention through a no-operation import there. But yes, it indeed require 0-1.0 normalized values.
